# Listening for changes to notification channel in app

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

So I have an app where I am creating notification channels for the different notification types the app will be sending out. In the app I have a PreferenceFragment that has a Preference in it that is showing the current settings of the notification channel. Clicking it will take the user to the specific channel setting in the android settings using the Settings.ACTION_CHANNEL_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS intent. The problem is, if they change the sound in the android settings after clicking that link, when they hit back they are taken back to my app, in the PreferenceFragment, but the preference still shows the old Sound that was set before they changed it.

Is there any possible way to listen for that, or maybe use startActivityForResult on the notification channel settings so when they hit back from there after updating my app will show the new information they just did there?

I know it is customary to show code when asking for help, but I really don't have any relevant code for this. I am just starting activity with the settings intent. I am more than happy to show what I do have if it might help. I have been searching for a couple days and come up with nothing for this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Does your ux design need for the user to return to the `PreferenceFragment`?

Comment: Yeah, because they can also customize the messages that the notifications send, so bringing them back to that same page is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know that users can only change the notification settings when they are in a different activity, you can refresh all of your information in `onResume()` to always have updated information when the user returns to your app.

Comment: I don't think the PreferenceFragment has an onResume though. The Preference fragment is located in a ViewPager as the 4th tab.

Comment: Every Fragment has an `onResume` method.